# Modx mFilter не работает

Tags: modx, поиск, фильтры, minishop2

Установил сниппет **mSearch** и он работает, но сниппет из этого же пакета который называется **mFilter** не работает. Посмотреть можете на сайте http://vsempopare.ru/produkcziya/zhenskaya-obuv/tufli/

Вот код вызова сниппета:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
        <div class="filter">
            <form action="[[~[[*id]]]]" method="post" id="mFilter">
                [[!mFilter?
                    &resources=`[[!getCatIds?parents=`27`]]`
                    &includeTVs=`1`
                    &includeMS=`1`
                    &includeMSList=`price,new,favorite,popular,size,color`
                    &sortFilters=`ms_new,ms_favorite,ms_popular,ms_size,ms_color,ms_price`
                    &tpl=`card-of.tpl`
                ]]

                [[-!mFilter? &resources=`[[!getCatIds?parents=`27`]]` &includeMSList=`price,new,favorite,popular,size,color`]]
                <input type="hidden" name="query" value="[[+mse.query]]">
                <input type="hidden" name="page" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="sort" value="ms_price,asc">
                <input type="hidden" name="limit" value="3">
                <input type="hidden" name="parents" value="[[+parents]]">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="filter" />
            </form>
        </div><!-- end_filter -->
    </div>
    <div class="span9" id="mItems"></div>
</div>

<link href="http://yandex.st/jquery-ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://yandex.st/jquery-ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/components/msearch/js/mfilter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
```

Но вне зависимости от проставленных меток выдает **"Ничего не найдено"**

Comment: На первом минишопе никто давно уже ничего не делает, когда есть второй. Твой вызов сделан именно для первого минишопа. Тут либо тебе заделаться крутым программером и самому решить свой вопрос (потому что никто таким больше не занимается уже довольно давно), либо поставить себе minishop2 и купить msearch2(если уж денег совсем нет - есть вариант собрать из исходников), а там и документация есть хорошая и все точно работает.

Answer (score 0):

Слеш перед `assets/components/msearch/js/mfilter.js` уберите.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?